# Need help with simple octree implementation

Tags: python, octree

Hello I'm trying to implement an octree, but when I query the centre positions they all return zero, but these should be offset from zero. Here is my code:

```
class Octree:

def __init__( self, _centre, _size ):
    '''
    Class to create an Octree

    @param: _centre: [float,float,float], position in world space for centre of octree
    @param: _size: float, length of one edge of the first cube, should be big enough to fit all data
    '''

    self.centre = _centre
    self.size = _size
    self.octreeNodes = []

def subdivideOctree( self, _subdivisions ):
    '''
    subdivides octree 

    @param: _subdivisions: int, number of times to subdivide octree
    '''



    for i in range(8):
        newCentre = self.centre

        if ((i&2) == 2):
                newCentre[0] += self.size * 0.25
        else:
                newCentre[0] -= self.size * 0.25

        if ((i&4) == 4):
                newCentre[1] += self.size * 0.25
        else:
                newCentre[1] -= self.size * 0.25

        if ((i&1) == 1):
                newCentre[2] += self.size * 0.25
        else:
                newCentre[2] -= self.size * 0.25

        print newCentre

        self.octreeNodes.append(Octree( newCentre, self.size * 0.5 ))

        if( _subdivisions > 0 ):
                self.octreeNodes[i].subdivideOctree( _subdivisions - 1 )

def isLeaf( self ):
    return self.octreeNodes == None

def getCentre( self ):
    return self.centre

def getSize( self ):
    return self.size

a = Octree([0,0,0], 2.0)
a.subdivideOctree(2)

print a.getCentre()
print a.octreeNodes[0].getCentre()
print a.octreeNodes[0]

for n in a.octreeNodes:
    for b in n.octreeNodes:
        print b.getCentre()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
newCentre = self.centre
```

then that doesn't create a new array, but it uses the same object instead. If you modify `newCentre`, `self.centre` gets modified as well. It probably stays 0, because it's symmetric.

Comment: Oh how can I create a new array from self.centre? And when I create a new Octree object as I have done recursively, does each object have a unique self.centre?

Comment: @cee012 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list and yes

Answer (score -1):

You have to do 
newCentre = self.centre[:]

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? That is the correct way to create a new list with the content from another list...